# プログラムからducuworksファイルを開けない。

Tags: python

pythonでdocuworksファイルを開くプログラムを書いたのですがエラーが出てしまいます。
エラーの内容は開きたいファイルに既にアクセスがあり、競合している？ようなので確認したのですが
ファイル自体は別に開いていないし、何もアクセスしていません。
いろいろ調べたのですがどうしても解決できず、アドバイスをお願いしたいです。

以下はエラーの内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\pythonProject\pycharm\test\main.py", line 9, in <module>
doc.open()
File "C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\pythonProject\pycharm\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\xdwlib\xdwfile.py", line 538, in open
self.handle = XDW_OpenDocumentHandleExW(self.pathname(), open_mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\pythonProject\pycharm\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\xdwlib\xdwapi.py", line 2422, in func
return api(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\pythonProject\pycharm\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\xdwlib\xdwapi.py", line 2477, in XDW_OpenDocumentHandleExW
TRY(DLL.XDW_OpenDocumentHandleExW, path, byref(doc_handle), byref(open_mode))
File "C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\pythonProject\pycharm\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\xdwlib\xdwapi.py", line 2282, in apifunc
raise XDWErrorFactory(result)
xdwlib.xdwapi.SharingViolationError: XDW_E_SHARING_VIOLATION (80070020)
```

以下ソースコード

```
import xdwlib
from xdwlib import xdwopen
from xdwlib.document import Document
import time

file_pass = r"C:\Users\moco_\OneDrive\デスクトップ\temp_folder\testfile.xdw"
doc = xdwopen(file_pass)
doc.open()
time.sleep(5)
doc.save()
doc.close()
```

Comment: エラーの直接の原因になっているかはわかりませんが、OneDrive 上のファイルを MS Office 以外からアクセスするとトラブルになる事例が多いです。別のフォルダに移動して試してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
先ほど別のフォルダ【以下パス】に移動して試しましたが、同じエラーが出ました。
file_pass = r"C:\Users\moco_\Documents\testfile.xdw"
原因がよくわからないです。。。

Comment: ユーザー毎のドキュメントフォルダもまだ少し配慮が必要そうなフォルダなので、C:\Workといったフォルダを作ってファイルを入れてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: "C:\work\testfile.xdw"
上記パスで試しましたがやはりだめです。。。。
タスクマネージャーを見てもdocuworksは起動していないので、なぜこのエラーがでるのか不明です。。。。

Comment: エラーコードやマクロ名からするとこのページ [Win32エラーコード一覧](http://ir9.jp/prog/ayu/win32err.htm) の `STIERR_SHARING_VIOLATION -2147024864 0x80070020 プロセスはファイルにアクセスできません。別のプロセスが使用中です。`と同じものだと思われます。動作確認作業などで複数回スクリプトやプログラムを動かして、その残滓が生きているとかかも？ いったんシステムをシャットダウン・再起動してまっさらな状態から試してみてはどうでしょう？ あと例えばEXCELだと別のフォルダの別のファイルでもファイル名が同じなら複数は開けないので、似たような仕組みがあったりしませんか？

Comment: PC自体をshutdownして再度起動させて試しましたが、やはり同じエラーが出ます。。。
お手上げです。。。

Comment: まあどうしようも無ければ作者に問い合わせてみてはどうでしょう？ [xdwlib - Python DocuWorks Library](https://xdwlib.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/) `xdwlib に関するご意見・ご要望は作者 (林秀樹) へお寄せください。` あるいはこんなツールでわかるかもしれませんね。[プロセス エクスプローラー V17.05](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdwopen()`はユーティリティ関数であり、指定されたパスの拡張子に応じて適切なクラスのオブジェクトを返すそうです。この関数は内部でファイルをオープンするはずです。

- [xdwlib/docs/howto.rst at master · hayasix/xdwlib | GitHub](https://github.com/hayasix/xdwlib/blob/master/docs/howto.rst)

`xdwopen()`で返ってきたオブジェクトに対して、さらに`doc.open()`を実行してしまっていることによって、すでに開いているファイルを再度開こうとして例外がスローされているのでは？

**どのライブラリやAPIにも通用することですが、まず公式のリファレンスとサンプルコードをよく読むことを推奨します。**

余談ですが、ファイルクローズを自動化するためにも、`with`文を使ったほうがよいと思います。

- [hayasix/xdwlib: A DocuWorks library. | GitHub](https://github.com/hayasix/xdwlib)

Comment: ご教授頂きありがとうございました。
自分の勉強不足でした。

Comment: @prog_526791 問題解決につながった回答であれば、「回答の承認」をお願いします。最初に本サイトのヘルプを熟読してください。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [質問にあたって - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)